Stripe restricted status for a connected account
I am able to create a connected accounts with charges enabled and payouts enabled using Stripe test keys. But when I went live and created a stripe connected account, it shows the account is restricted in the Stripe dashboard. I am using AWS lambda to write the account creation code in python in the backend. I have two lambda functions' code below. One for generating stripe account id, one for generating stripe account creation url. I am just writing the api calls here and not the lambda handler because it worked for test keys. Can someone explain why this is so? Has anyone faced this issue while going live? Do I need to add some more parameters in the below api calls?
I tried to create a stripe account using the below code.
import json
import http.client
import urllib.parse

def create_stripe_account(user_name, email):
    user_name = user_name
    email = email
    
    url = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/accounts"
    api_key = "sk_live_123"
    
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {api_key}",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
    print("log-1")
    
    parameters = {
        "type": "express",
        "country": "US",
        "email": email,
        "capabilities[card_payments][requested]": True,
        "capabilities[transfers][requested]": True,
        "business_type": "individual",
        "business_profile[mcc]": 5971,
        "business_profile[name]": user_name,
        "business_profile[product_description]": "Artwork"
    }
    print("log-2")
    
    # json_data = json.dumps(parameters)
    encoded_parameters = urllib.parse.urlencode(parameters)
    request_body = encoded_parameters.encode("utf-8")
    print("log-3")
    
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.stripe.com")
    conn.request("POST", url, body=request_body, headers=headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    print("log-4")
    
    if response.status == 200:
        response_data = response.read().decode("utf-8")
        return response_data, response.status
    else:
        print(f"Error: Invalid HTTP response ({response.status})")
        response_data = response.read().decode("utf-8")
        print(f"Response data: {response_data}")
        return response_data, response.status

Using the above code, I retrieved stripe account id and generated a stripe account creation URL using the below code.
import json
import http.client
import urllib.parse
import json

def create_account_link(stripe_account_id):
    stripe_account_id = stripe_account_id
    test_flight_url = "https://testflight.apple.com/join/57vVCOVf"
    
    # Define the URL and API key
    url = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/account_links"
    api_key = "sk_live_123"

    # Define the parameters
    parameters = {
        "account": stripe_account_id,
        "refresh_url": test_flight_url,
        "return_url": test_flight_url,
        "type": "account_onboarding"
    }

    # Encode the parameters
    encoded_parameters = urllib.parse.urlencode(parameters)
    body = encoded_parameters.encode("utf-8")

    # Define the headers
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {api_key}",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }

    # Establish connection
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.stripe.com")

    # Send POST request
    conn.request("POST", url, body, headers)

    # Get response
    response = conn.getresponse()

    # Read and decode response data
    response_data = response.read().decode("utf-8")

    # Print response status code and data
    print("Status Code:", response.status)
    print("Response:", response_data)

    if response.status == 200:
        return response_data, response.status
    else:
        print(f"Error: Invalid HTTP response ({response.status})")
        print(f"Response data: {response_data}")
        return response_data, response.status


I'd recommend going to the Connect Dashboard > Select connected account > Click Action required tab under Activity section > Check the information why the account is still restricted

Some requirements might take time to get verified. Before the information is verified, the account will remain in restricted
